# loop for to print a dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, for-loop, python-2.x

I'd like to find a way to print a list of dictionnaries line by line, so that the result be clear and easy to read 
the list is like this.

---

```
myList = {'1':{'name':'x',age:'18'},'2':{'name':'y',age:'19'},'3':{'name':'z',age:'20'}...}
```

---

and the result should be like this:

```
>>> '1':{'name':'x',age:'18'} 
    '2':{'name':'y',age:'19'}
    '3':{'name':'z',age:'20'} ...
```

Comment: I just edited my question actually it's a dictionnary containing dictionnaries and i've tried for d in myList: print d but it only prints the first value of the dictionnary each time..

Comment: yeah i just edited it =)

Comment: If this is for python interpreter you can use ipython. It automatically pretty prints your dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using your example:

```
>>> myList = {'1':{'name':'x','age':'18'},'2':{'name':'y','age':'19'},'3':{'name':'z','age':'20'}}
>>> for k, d in myList.items():
    print k, d

1 {'age': '18', 'name': 'x'}
3 {'age': '20', 'name': 'z'}
2 {'age': '19', 'name': 'y'}
```

---

More examples:

A list of dictionaries:

```
>>> l = [{'a':'1'},{'b':'2'},{'c':'3'}]
>>> for d in l:
    print d

{'a': '1'}
{'b': '2'}
{'c': '3'}
```

A dictionary of dictionaries:

```
>>> D = {'d1': {'a':'1'}, 'd2': {'b':'2'}, 'd3': {'c':'3'}}
>>> for k, d in D.items():
    print d  

{'b': '2'}
{'c': '3'}
{'a': '1'}
```

If you want the key of the dicts:

```
>>> D = {'d1': {'a':'1'}, 'd2': {'b':'2'}, 'd3': {'c':'3'}}
>>> for k, d in D.items():
    print k, d

d2 {'b': '2'}
d3 {'c': '3'}
d1 {'a': '1'}
```

Comment: that's exactly what i wanted i have just edited my question so it be clearer =) thank you

Comment: @InbarRose +1, Also you might choose to `print repr(k), d`

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import json
>>> dicts = {1: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 2: {'c': 3}, 3: {'d': 4, 'e': 5, 'f':6}}
>>> print(json.dumps(dicts, indent=4))
{
    "1": {
        "a": 1, 
        "b": 2
    }, 
    "2": {
        "c": 3
    }, 
    "3": {
        "d": 4, 
        "e": 5, 
        "f": 6
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One more option - [pprint](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html), made for pretty-printing.

> The pprint module provides a capability to “pretty-print” arbitrary Python data structures in a form which can be used as input to the interpreter.

List of dictionaries:

```
from pprint import pprint

l = [{'a':'1'},{'b':'2'},{'c':'3'}]
pprint(l, width=1)
```

Output:

```
[{'a': '1'},
 {'b': '2'},
 {'c': '3'}]
```

---

Dictionary with dictionaries in values:

```
from pprint import pprint

d = {'a':{'b':'c'}},{'d':{'e':'f'}}
pprint(d, width=1)
```

Output:

```
({'a': {'b': 'c'}},
 {'d': {'e': 'f'}})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
myList = {'1':{'name':'x','age':'18'},
          '2':{'name':'y','age':'19'},
          '3':{'name':'z','age':'20'}}
for item in myList:
    print(item,':',myList[item])
```

Output:

```
3 : {'age': '20', 'name': 'z'}
2 : {'age': '19', 'name': 'y'}
1 : {'age': '18', 'name': 'x'}
```

item is used to iterate keys in the dict, and `myList[item]` is the value corresponding to the current key.

Comment: This is much better done iterating over the `items()` in the dictionary, like in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16277582/1561176) but this is the same approach I used. +1